# s3 private files not showing sometimes

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have been facing an issue recently, when I am accessing the private s3 files, sometimes the files get displayed and sometimes doesn't. Mainly the issue is happening with Google Chrome.
The file is accessed through PHP library provided by Amazon S3, the url is like

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/{bucket_name}/{file_name}?AWSAccessKeyId={access_key}&Expires={expire_time}&Signature={signature}
```

No change has been done to configuration as these files were running smoothly before this issue!

Please help me.

Comment: You'll need to be more clear about what happens when it doesn't work.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot the contents from the files are not displaying, sometimes it fetches the data and sometimes it fails, this problem started 2 days earlier

Comment: Define "sometimes it fails" more. 404? 403? Something else?

Comment: Given an example, I am using the file to display those content in the front-end, getting the data through PHP library of AWS, now the content like text sometimes get displayed and sometimes not! Why is this happening! I do not have a single clue!

Comment: We still lack enough information to understand the nature of the problem.  What do you see when it fails?  Error message? White screen?  Is the browser accessing S3 directly or is php fetching from S3 and returning the content to the browser?

Comment: php fetching from s3 and returning the content to the browser, the contents are sometimes displayed and sometimes do not, well  the same code worked fine in development environment @Michael-sqlbot